# what to do during an 8 hour layover at Haneda airport in the evening (5pm- 1am)?

Tags: japan, layovers, tokyo, hnd

I have an 8 hour layover at Haneda airport in the evening before continuing to my destination and i would like to get out of the airport and explore a little bit.